# Print once in If-Else (Python; please read description)

Tags: python, printing

In a game, I want to print "Good afternoon" once when score is 2 in Python.

```
if score == 2:
   print("Good afternoon!")
```

This program prints until score is 2.
What should I do to print it once when score reaches 2?

Comment: We will need more context for this. Is this code executed in a loop? You might try `if score == 2 and not ALREADY_PRINTED: print(...); ALREADY_PRINTED = True`

Comment: _This program prints until score is 2_ --> No! Please [edit] your question and add an [mre]

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is intended to be used for questions related to the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's in a game your code is executed in a loop so it will always print("Good afternoon") when the score equals 2.

So you can use a boolean that you may declare in your init function block:

```
is_score_printed = false
```

Then:

```
if score == 2 and not is_score_printed:
    print("Good afternoon!")
    is_score_printed = true
```